# Getting an undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table

I understand what this error is saying but I don't know why I'm getting it? I'm trying to display a table with the index action, everything seems pretty standard but for some reasons this error has occurred. I'll post my code for clarity.

**view**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @subsriber.each do |subsriber| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= subscriber.first_name %></td>
          <td><%= subscriber.last_name %></td>
          <td><%= subscriber.email %></td>
          <td><%= subscriber.phone_number %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**controller**

```
def index
  @subscriber = Subscriber.all
end
```

I know I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typo error, in your controller you defined `@subscriber` but used `@subsriber` in the view!

Btw, conventionally, You may use `@subscribers` instead of `@subscriber`, it is clearer!